# Why does NSMutableURLRequest instantiation cause a crash?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to create a NSMutableURLRequest like this:

```
NSURL *URLWithString = [
    NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",
    urlString,
    datas
];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URLWithString] autorelease];
```

When I run it on my iPhone 4S, the app crashes and I get the following exception:

> 2012-10-30 15:58:53.495 [429:907] -[__NSCFString absoluteURL]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd74a90
>
> 2012-10-30 15:58:53.497 [429:907] --- Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd74a90'
>
> --- First throw call stack:
>
> (0x361b62a3 0x344c697f 0x361b9e07 0x361b8531 0x3610ff68 0x3611363f
>   0x320396e7 0x32039551 0x320394ed 0x33bde661 0x33bde597 0x387e1
>   0x376d9f1f 0x376da9a9 0x341c535d 0x3618b173 0x3618b117 0x36189f99
>   0x360fcebd 0x360fcd49 0x366392eb 0x374db301 0x37cc1 0x37c58)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `absoluteURL` in some other code? The crash is telling you that you are trying to use the `absoluteURL` message on an NSString instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of issues:
For a start look into how to invoke NSString and NSURL methods. I have done it for the code you have pasted.

```
NSURL * myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",urlString,datas]];
```

and

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myUrl] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your NSURL creation code is wrong.

```
NSURL *URLWithString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?%@", urlString, datas];
```

Here, you are trying to create an NSURL directly with an [NSString class method (`stringWithFormat`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_). The result is that your variable `URLWithString` will be of the wrong type, and when you send it an NSURL message you'll get a crash like you are getting.

To fix this you need to create an NSString of the URL address first, and instantiate an NSURL using that, like so:

```
NSString *completeURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", urlString, datas];
NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: completeURLString];
```

(Technically, these two lines can be combined; I've separated them to make it clear what's going on.)

Also, whilst probably not related to your crash, you shouldn't call your URL variable `URLWithString`, as that is the name for a [class method of NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB). Make sure to come up with a unique name for it, and to start it with a lower case character (at the very least, this will make your code easier to decipher for others).